# how to use a javascript variable inside html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in this There are two field One is Search and other is Option When i select any value from Search field the value of Option field will change.Value of Second field are different datalist defines as datalist1,datalist2,datalist3.....I want the value given in List attribute of Second filed to be same as the variable value in java script.i Tried the following code this code is not giving any output.

```js
  

  function random() {
      var a = document.getElementById('search').value;
      if (a === "sampleid") {
        var datalist = datalist1;
      } else if (a === "facility") {
        var datalist = datalist1;
      } else if (a === "user") {
        var datalist = datalist3;
      } else if (a === "affiliation") {
        var datalist = datalist4;
      } else if (a === "status") {
        var datalist = datalist5;
      } else if (a === "btr") {
        var datalist = datalist6;
      } else if (a === "type") {
        var datalist = datalist7;
      }

      document.getElementById('option').innerHTML = datalist;

    }
```

```html
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="search-sample.php">
      <div class="col-md-5" align="center">
        <label class="search">SEARCH BY-</label>
        <select type="text" name="SEARCH" id="search" class="form-control" onchange="random()">
          <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
          <option value="sampleid">SAMPLE-ID</option>
          <option value="facility">FACILITY</option>
          <option value="user">USER NAME</option>
          <option value="affiliation">AFFILIATION</option>
          <option value="status">STATUS</option>
          <option value="btr">BTR</option>
          <option value="type">SAMPLE TYPE</option>
          <option value="date">DATE</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5" align="center">
        <label class="search">OPTION</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option" name="facility" list=< ?php echo "datalist" ?> />
      </div>
    <datalist id="datalist1"> 
 
 <option value=""> </option>
 <?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * from  tblfacility order by sampleid asc";
 $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
 $query->execute();
 $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 $cnt=1;
 if($query->rowCount() > 0)
 {
 foreach($results as $result)
 {               ?> 
     <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?></option>
  <?php }} ?>
 </datalist>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please update the code with datalist mocks and the code for 
 upperCaseF(this)

Comment: You mean `var datalist = document.getElementById("datalist1")`

Comment: @mplungjani want the value of varr datalist to be ther in the second field of form Option list value

Comment: There is no need for PHP in this question. It is purely JavaScript related

Comment: This also does not make sense `list=< ?php echo "datalist" ?> />` because there is no _datalist_ with id `datalist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

1. Use quotes around the IDs of the datalists
2. Use setAttribute of the list attribute of the input

```js
function random() {
  var a = document.getElementById('search').value,
    datalist = "datalist1";
  if (a === "sampleid") {
    datalist = "datalist1";
  } else if (a === "facility") {
    datalist = "datalist1";
  } else if (a === "user") {
    datalist = "datalist2";
  } else if (a === "affiliation") {
    datalist = "datalist3";
  } else if (a === "status") {
    datalist = "datalist1";
  } else if (a === "btr") {
    datalist = "datalist2";
  } else if (a === "type") {
    datalist = "datalist3";
  }
  
  const inp = document.getElementById('option');
  inp.value="";
  inp.setAttribute("list", datalist)

}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="search-sample.php">
  <div class="col-md-5" align="center">
    <label class="search">SEARCH BY-</label>
    <select type="text" name="SEARCH" id="search" class="form-control" onchange="random()">
      <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
      <option value="sampleid">SAMPLE-ID</option>
      <option value="facility">FACILITY</option>
      <option value="user">USER NAME</option>
      <option value="affiliation">AFFILIATION</option>
      <option value="status">STATUS</option>
      <option value="btr">BTR</option>
      <option value="type">SAMPLE TYPE</option>
      <option value="date">DATE</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5" align="center">
    <label class="search">OPTION</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option" name="facility" list="" />
  </div>
  <datalist id="datalist1">
    <option value="A"> </option>
    <option value="B"> </option>
    <option value="C"> </option>
    <option value="D"> </option>
  </datalist>
  <datalist id="datalist2">
    <option value="AA"> </option>
    <option value="BB"> </option>
    <option value="CC"> </option>
    <option value="DD"> </option>
  </datalist>
  <datalist id="datalist3">
    <option value="AAA"> </option>
    <option value="BBB"> </option>
    <option value="CCC"> </option>
    <option value="DDD"> </option>
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see update - I clear the field when changing list

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is assign a datalist to the "option" input based on the selected value in the select element, something like the following cut–down version of the OP:

```js
// Select is a reference to the select element and
// is passed from the listener
function random(select) {

  // Map select value to id of list to display
  let map = {'sampleid': 'datalist1',
             'facility': 'datalist2',
             'user': 'datalist3'
            };
  // Get the option input
  let option = document.getElementById('option');
  // Clear the value
  option.value = '';
  // Assign the appropriate list
  option.setAttribute('list', map[select.value]);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>SEARCH BY-</label>
  <select name="SEARCH" id="search" onchange="random(this)">
    <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
    <option value="sampleid">SAMPLE-ID</option>
    <option value="facility">FACILITY</option>
    <option value="user">USER</option>
  </select>

  <!-- opton input to display options -->
  <input list="" id="option" name="option">

  <!-- datalists of options -->
  <datalist id="datalist1">
    <option value="datalist1 A">
    <option value="datalist1 B">
    <option value="datalist1 C">
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="datalist2">
    <option value="datalist2 AA">
    <option value="datalist2 BB">
    <option value="datalist2 CC">
  </datalist>

  <datalist id="datalist3">
    <option value="datalist3 AAA">
    <option value="datalist3 BBB">
    <option value="datalist3 CCC">
  </datalist>
</form>
```

You should probably also disable the input if the selected value is the first one (i.e. select.selectedIndex = 0).

Comment: This is identical to my answer except for the map

Comment: @mplungjan—great minds think alike. :-) You posted while I was working on it. You also need to clear the value of the input before setting the list attribute, otherwise if the user changes the selected option, the datalist doesn't seem to be assigned correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Use value instead of innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('option').value= datalist;
```

Comment: @J LP J  it is giving the following output in Option field   [OBJECT HTMLDATALISTELEMENT]

Comment: Make sure datalist is string. Looks like you are forming object in the function for populating datalist.